# Reproducing a graph using an incidence matrix

Tags: graph-theory

I am very new to graph theory. In fact, I've only begun studying the subject three days ago. So please have mercy if this is a meaningless question!

It occurred to me while studying graph isomorphisms that a person ought to be able to take an incidence matrix and reproduce from that matrix a graph that is - while perhaps not the original - isomorphic to the original graph. Is this true? If so, any good proofs?

Answer (score 3):

A graph is determined (up to isomorphism) by the list of vertices and list of edges. The incidence matrix is simply a way to encode the list of vertices and edges. Since the graph is defined by which vertices that are adjacent, and the incidence matrix is one way to present the adjacencies, you can reproduce the graph from the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Hmmm...so then you can also confirm whether or not two graphs are isomorphic by simply comparing adjacency matrices, yes? This stuff is all still a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @mathtastic Yes, sort of. Two isomorphic graphs have adjacency matrices that are equal up to the order of the rows and columns (since an isomorphism is basically a relabeling of the vertices), so it's not always easy to compare them in practice.